# Help using the REST api and Java

Tags: api, rest-api

I'm having a bit of issues with the REST api, I can't find any documentation that shows me all the fields that I can use and the official documentation at http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html seems incomplete...

One issue is that I can't set the website_id and category_id when I create a new product.

Another issue, I can upload a picture but I don't know which fields I need to set to make it base image / small image / thumbnail...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do with the REST API?

Comment: My client has some old software running in their warehouses, I'm trying to build a java application/library in the middle that can create/update/delete products and receive new orders... I'm able to create the product but there are some fields such as the website id, category id that I'm not able to set programmatically because they are not documented in the rest api...